# Plugin for Firefox: imports a library that uses eval and conflicts with Content-Security-Policy

Tags: javascript, firefox, plugins

I'm writing a plugin for Firefox that uses a trained neural network model saved in ONNX format (model.onnx). The plugin is intended to be fully self-contained and "local"(no Server-side), written in JavaScript (I hope to publish it on the Firefox store and make it accessible). However, I'm facing issues with the usage of the onnxruntime-web library.

I have imported this library, both through direct import of the ort.min.js file and through webpack, but I'm encountering a Content-Security-Policy error due to the presence of eval() functions. Now, I cannot change the parameters of the Content-Security-Policy as it would make it impossible for other users to use this plugin. My question is, are there any other techniques? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the special
`Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'wasm-unsafe-eval'`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src